# R: Plotting lines and symbols with one legend, and then highlighting some data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

What I would like to do is plot some data with lines and points, with the color, line type, and point style varying.  Then I want to plot a subset of data with the same attributes as the first plot.  Then, make a third plot with the subset of data and also the non selected data shown in grey.

I would also like the legend to be the same width for the three plots, and to have 10 columns.

Here is my "attempt"

```
# Create sample data
set.seed(1)
nSamples=1000
dt<-data.table(src=sample(paste('SRC-',11:25,sep=''),nSamples,replace=TRUE),
               id=sample(1001:1150,nSamples,replace=TRUE),
               dhr=sample(seq(.1,2,.1),nSamples,replace=TRUE),
               dcnt=sample(1:5,nSamples,replace=TRUE))
dt$hr<-ave(dt$dhr,dt$id,FUN=cumsum) 
dt$cnt<-ave(dt$dcnt,dt$id,FUN=cumsum) 

# Set plot characteristics
dt$linetype <- factor((dt$id %% 4)+1)
dt$color <- factor(dt$id)
dt$shape <- factor((dt$id %% 6)+1)

# Question 1: How to get the legend to correspond to the plot (color, linetype, symbol)
# and have 10 columns
ggplot(dt,aes(x=hr,y=cnt,group=id,color=color,linetype=linetype))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(shape=dt$shape))+
  ggtitle('All ID') +
  xlab("Time (hr)") +
  ylab("Repair (Part count)") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=10,title='ID'))

# Question 2: Select some source data to be plotted.
# How to plot with same 'colored' lines / symbols as plot 1
srcIndex <- grep('SRC-14',dt$src)
srcData<-dt[srcIndex,]
nonsrcData<-dt[-srcIndex,]

ggplot(data=NULL,aes(x=hr,y=cnt,group=id,color=color,linetype=linetype))+
#  geom_line(data=nonsrcData, color='grey') +
#  geom_point(data=nonsrcData, color='grey', shape=nonsrcData$shape)+
  ggtitle('SRC-14 ID') +
  xlab("Time (hr)") +
  ylab("Repair (Part count)") +
  geom_line(data=srcData) +
  geom_point(data=srcData,aes(shape=srcData$shape))+
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=10,title='ID'))

# Question 3: 
# How to plot the nonsource  plot in part 1 with 'grey' lines / symbols, and then 
# overlay with 'colored' lines / symbols

ggplot(data=NULL,aes(x=hr,y=cnt,group=id,color=color,linetype=linetype))+
  geom_line(data=nonsrcData, color='grey') +
  geom_point(data=nonsrcData, color='grey', shape=nonsrcData$shape)+
  ggtitle('SRC-14 ID') +
  xlab("Time (hr)") +
  ylab("Repair (Part count)") +
  geom_line(data=srcData) +
  geom_point(data=srcData,aes(shape=srcData$shape))+
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=10,title='ID'))
```

This plot needs the legend corrected so that a single legend shows the variation in line type and color and also the variation in symbol, with the symbol color matching the line color.  Also, remove the two extra legends.

[image]

This plot has the same problem(s) as figure 1, with the legends.  Scale should be the same as fig 1.
[image]

The 3rd figure should be similar to the 2nd, with the other data added in grey.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code generates the 3 plots with the correct legend.

```
set.seed(1)
nSamples=1000
dt<-data.table(src=sample(paste('SRC-',11:25,sep=''),nSamples,replace=TRUE),
               id=sample(1001:1150,nSamples,replace=TRUE),
               dhr=sample(seq(.1,2,.1),nSamples,replace=TRUE),
               dcnt=sample(1:5,nSamples,replace=TRUE))
dt$hr<-ave(dt$dhr,dt$id,FUN=cumsum) 
dt$cnt<-ave(dt$dcnt,dt$id,FUN=cumsum) 

# Set plot characteristics
dt$linetype <- factor((dt$id %% 4)+1)
dt$color <- factor(dt$id)
dt$shape <- factor((dt$id %% 6)+1)

# Question 1: How to get the legend to correspond to the plot (color, linetype, symbol)
# and have 10 columns
dt$id <- factor(dt$id)
sortid<-order(dt$id)
unik <- which(!duplicated(dt$id[sortid]))
unik <- sortid[unik]

ggplot(dt, aes(hr, cnt, group = id)) + 
  geom_line(size=1, aes(color=dt$color, linetype=dt$linetype)) +
  geom_point(data = dt, 
             aes(hr, cnt, group = id, color = id, shape=shape),size=3)  +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(ncol=10,title='ID',
                               override.aes = list(shape = as.integer(dt$shape[unik]),
                                                   linetype = as.integer(dt$linetype[unik]))),
         shape = FALSE, linetype = FALSE) +
  ggtitle('ALL ID') +
  xlab("Time (hr)") +
  ylab("Repair (Part count)") +
  xlim(0, 25) + ylim(0,60)

# Question 2: Select some source data to be plotted.
# How to plot with same 'colored' lines / symbols as plot 1
srcIndex <- grep('SRC-14',dt$src)
srcData<-dt[srcIndex,]
nonsrcData<-dt[-srcIndex,]

sort_src_id<-order(srcData$id)
unik_src <- which(!duplicated(srcData$id[sort_src_id]))
unik_src <- sort_src_id[unik_src]

ggplot(srcData, aes(hr, cnt, group = id)) + 
  geom_line(size=1, aes(color=srcData$color, linetype=srcData$linetype)) +
  geom_point(data = srcData, 
             aes(hr, cnt, group = id, color = id, shape=shape),size=3)  +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(ncol=10,title='ID',
                               override.aes = list(shape = as.integer(srcData$shape[unik_src]),
                                                   linetype = as.integer(srcData$linetype[unik_src]))),
         shape = FALSE, linetype = FALSE) +
  ggtitle('SRC-14') +
  xlab("Time (hr)") +
  ylab("Repair (Part count)") +
  xlim(0, 25) + ylim(0,60) 


# Question 3: 
# How to plot the nonsource  plot in part 1 with 'grey' lines / symbols, and then 
# overlay with 'colored' lines / symbols

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(size=.5, color='grey', aes(x=nonsrcData$hr,
                                       y=nonsrcData$cnt,
                                       linetype=nonsrcData$linetype,
                                       group=nonsrcData$id)) +
  geom_point(size=1,color='grey',aes(x=nonsrcData$hr,
                                     y=nonsrcData$cnt,
                                     shape=nonsrcData$shape,
                                     group=nonsrcData$id)) +
  geom_line(data=srcData, size=1.5, aes(hr, cnt, 
                        group = id,
                        color=color, linetype=linetype)) +
  geom_point(data = srcData, size=3,
             aes(hr, cnt, group = id, color = color, shape=shape))  +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(ncol=10,title='ID',
                               override.aes = list(shape = as.integer(srcData$shape[unik_src]),
                                                   linetype = as.integer(srcData$linetype[unik_src]))),
         shape = FALSE, linetype = FALSE) +
  ggtitle('SRC-14') +
  xlab("Time (hr)") +
  ylab("Repair (Part count)") +
  xlim(0, 25) + ylim(0,60)
```

The code above generates all 3 plots.  Here is the 1st showing all the data, with the legend corrected.

[image]

Here is the the third plot showing the selected subset highlighted, with the legend corrected
[image]